# Python как управлять консольной программой?

Tags: python

Есть консольная программа .exe которая задает вопросы в консоле и принимает ответы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при помощи python считывать вопрос и вставлять в зависимости от вопроса нужный ответ Y либо N?

```
output = subprocess.check_call(['program.exe'], shell=True)
```

Данный код запускает программу, но как мне считывать вопросы и делать ответы, именно программно взаимодействовать?)

Comment: Читать полностью https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-subprocess.html  Класс subprocess.Popen

Comment: Я делаю `with Popen(["program.exe"], stdout=PIPE) as proc:
    log.write(proc.stdout.read())` - не срабатывает. Дайте готовый пример как запустить программу и получить вопрос, затем ответить на него и получить следующий вопрос, опять ответить и тд.